# UITextView - changing frame adds right padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UISlider` which can be used to resize a `UITextView`.
Before resizing the `textview`, everything looks ok, but after changing its frame for several times, it adds a padding to the right.

Before:
[image: Before resizing]
After:
[image: After resizing]

The `textview` (`_tvInput`) is the one on the top, and it's not placed in any other view container.

Here's the code that I use for changing its frame:

```
-(IBAction)widthChanged:(UISlider *)sender{
    CGRect frame = _tvInput.frame;
    frame.size.width = sender.value;
    frame.size.height = MIN(_tvInput.contentSize.height, [self tvMaxHeight]);
    if (sender.value<=_tvInput.superview.frame.size.width-20) {
        frame.origin.x = (_tvInput.superview.frame.size.width-frame.size.width)/2;
    }
    _tvInput.frame = frame;
}
```

So, any ideas what causes this, and more importantly how it can be fixed?
I tried resetting the `contentInset` of the `textView`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I also tried setting the `contentSize` manually, but no luck with that either.

Comment: Check by debugging if this mess up happens when textField's height is maxHeight.

Comment: @Akash thanks for your response. Even if I only change the width (leave the height and origin as they are), the padding is still added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man.. so I managed to fix it by changing this line (notice the conversion from float to int):

```
frame.size.width = (int)sender.value;
```

Not sure why that would cause an issue, by the looks of it the fractional part from changing the width kept on adding to the right padding.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten bitten a few times by this too. I now use textView.frame = CGRectIntegral(theFrame);